# Please grant me an accurate explanation of diode reverse bias mechanism

Tags: semiconductor-physics

[image]
Consider the image above.

Now I am an electron in that depletion region. I was not here initially, I was in the wire (free-moving electron of a copper atom) or perhaps battery (...of an ion?) but now I have been pushed here.

I feel attracted to the positive charges (which are for example phosphorous atoms with four valence electrons, hence the + charge) at the same time I also feel the repulsion from the negative terminal of the battery. I feel tempted (as well as all my electron friends) to move across the border and happily combine with the phosphorous ions, which is not happening. So what stops me there??

Update: I am expecting to see answers that require knowledge about solid state physics particularly band gap and band theory, which I do not know enough about and need to get a lot more reading. Can anyone please confirm this so I can move on feeling a little more assured and come back to this after I know enough about solid state physics.

Comment: Are you asking about the non-zero reverse current due to, e.g., thermal generation of electron-hole pairs within the depletion region?

Comment: Yeah, in fact I am asking why is there only a small reverse current OR why is there huge effective resistance in reverse bias OR what makes the depletion region unable to conduct current because it seems to me that the electrons (my friends and I) are quite mobile.

Comment: *"what makes the depletion region unable to conduct current"* - it's called the *depletion* region precisely because the region has been *depleted* of mobile charge carriers.  Don't forget that there is an electric field through the depletion region and so a mobile charge carrier cannot remain there.  From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depletion_region):  - *"The depletion region is so named because it is formed from a conducting region by removal of all free charge carriers, leaving none to carry a current."*

Comment: Free carriers in a reverse biased depletion region occur through Shockley-Reid-Hall generation-recombination processes, or absorption of a photon/passage of a charged particle.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri Exactly what I am trying to ask - why am I immobile? (I refer myself to one of the electrons in there) What makes me immobile?

Answer (score 0):

I won't try to answer your whole question, because it would take a couple of book chapters. But I'll try to address what seems to be your main misunderstanding.

> why am I immobile? (I refer myself to one of the electrons in there) What makes me immobile?

If you're an (conduction band) electron or (valence band) hole, you aren't immobile. You're just not in the depletion region to begin with. The depletion region doesn't block current by making carriers immobile, it blocks current by not having any mobile carriers in it.

If a mobile carrier is somehow introduced into the depletion region, it will produce a current. This is exactly how photodiodes work. Light falling on the depletion region excites electron-hole pairs. The field in the depletion region sweeps the two carriers in opposite direction, and we call it "photocurrent".

Comment: Thank you for your response.  The p-side of the depletion region is negatively charged, because of the accumulated excess electrons, which have been pushed here to fill in the holes of the trivalent atoms e.g. boron.  Aren't these electrons carriers? Or are they somehow locked in the valence band and that is why they are not counted as carriers? I understand that on the n-side of depletion region, electrons are taken away from the pentavalent atoms (hence the + charge), but my intuition tells me electrons can still move on this region and actually are easily attracted to here by the + charge.

Comment: The negative charge in the depletion region on the p-side comes from ionized impurity atoms. These charges are localized and immobile, not mobile carriers. These electrons aren't in the valence or conduction band, they're in states associated with the impurity atoms.

Comment: Those electrons come from somewhere else to the impurity atoms (boron) and the boron atoms are said to be ionized. The one extra electron compared to the protons in each boron atom makes it negatively charged. You said that these extra electrons aren't in either valence or conduction band but  in other states. What are the states? And, shouldn't an extra electron be in either one of valence band or conduction band of the ionized boron atom, unless its energy level is not within the range of valence energy band and conduction energy band?

Comment: The presence of acceptor impurities introduces new states that aren't part of the valence of the conduction band, and don't behave like v.b. or c.b. states (for example, an electron in one of these states isn't mobile). The electrons that provide the negative space charge in the p-side of the depletion region are in these states.

Comment: Also, the boron atoms don't have their own v.b. and c.b. because the boron atoms aren't spaced together densely enough for their associated states to interact and form bands.

Comment: Oh I see, if that's the case, I should be able to set aside majority of my doubts in that those electrons mentioned are somehow bound and not be able to move around. I should go about finding more information about this phenomenon, particularly about ionization and band theory etc. Thank you.

Comment: However, how does it explain when forward bias is now applied after reverse bias, those electrons become mobile again and the diode discharges just like a capacitor.

Answer (score 0):

The title of your question mentions a "reverse bias mechanism", but in the text of your question there is no reference to it nor do you explain what you mean by "reverse bias mechanism".

Your question seems to boil down to why the electrons do not recombine with the ionized donors in the depletion zone. This is very easily answered. Electrons can be bound to an ionized donor in the semiconductor crystal lattice much like an electron is bound to a proton in a hydrogen atom and it can be calculated in a similar way. The main difference lies in the much lower binding energy (or ionization) of the electron to the ion due to the much larger effective permittivity of the semiconductor and the lower effective mass of the electrons in the crystal. The ionization energy of phosphorus is only about 45meV which is comparable to the thermal energy kT at room temperature. Therefore at room temperature, according to the Fermi occupation statistics, most phosphorus donors are ionized, i.e., they have released their electron into the conduction band. Going to lower temperatures, more and more P ions will catch an electron, become neutral and thus do not act as an active dopant any longer. This is the so-called donor freeze-out.